# Install / run CodeSniffer on Windows... Is $ required?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I understand that this question seems to be a little silly, but I'm completely clueless as to how to run CodeSniffer.

I followed [this page](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/docs) and several other blogs or internet articles, but none of them give explanations which seem to be really comprehensive.

At least I'm 100% sure that `pear` has successfully been installed and now it's in the same directory as `php`.
However, I still can't run it. Here is a pic which indicates it.

[image]

As the pear's page says, I thought I need to have `$`, but it isn't recognized as a batch nor any other program.

I also assumed that the current directory was supposed to be the same one as `php`, but changing the directory to this directory didn't solve this issue either.

I'd appreciate if you'd give any advice.

Comment: Are you referring to the $ at the start of the command, as in `$ phpcs menu.php`? In which case `$` is just the prompt. On windows, this is `>` and you don't actually type it

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was  referring to the $ at the start of the command, like `$ phpcs menu.php`. So, is it right to consider that `$` is ignorable for command prompt on Windows (as long as I'm using `>` at the right position)?

Comment: This doesn't help your problem, but just a note that the latest docs are on the Github wiki: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki (I've lost access to remove them from the PEAR website)

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign is a common prompt character. It serves the same purpose as `>` in your screenshot. It is not intended that you type it as part of the command.

In the documentation you link to, it can be used to distinguish between lines of input you are supposed to type and lines of output you should expect to see.